# How to disable Latte dock in KDE?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, dock

I just can't find how to turn off the Latte dock

[image: Latte dock]

Answer (score 8):

1. Right click on the latte dock, then go to: **Layouts > Configure**
   [[Screenshot] Open Latte Dock Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPyMB.png)
2. On Latte Dock Settings, select: **File > Quit Latte**
   [[Screenshot] Quit Latte Dock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fG3Q4.png)
3. Disable/remove it from autostart. Open **System Settings**, go to: **Workspace > Startup and Shutdown > Autostart**, or just type "Autostart" from search menu bar. Click on **Latte**, Then remove it by click button "-" (Remove)
   [[Screenshot] Remove Latte Dock from Autostart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQ80w.png)

Comment: Very useful tip.

Comment: Seems obsolete. Can't find any way to show __Layouts > Configure__

Comment: I can in Kubuntu 20.04, but it's a bit old.

Answer (score 2):

try to disable it in system settings->startup & shutdown->autostart

Answer (score 1):

You can remove it:

```bsh
sudo apt remove latte-dock
```

Comment: Yes, I know that I can remove it, but I wonder if there is any way to just disable it, without removing it from system?